# Can we transfer data between two iPhone devices using NFC in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, nfc, data-transfer, nfc-p2p

With the release of iOS 13, iOS NFC core framework has added API's to write on NFC tags. But does this mean that now we can transfer data between two iPhone devices using NFC APIs.

Writing and reading on NFC tags works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not directly between two phones.  You can read from a tag and write to a tag, but iOS doesn't provide support for Card Emulation.

This means that you can't make iPhone "A" *look like a tag*, which is what would be necessary for iPhone "B to read data directly.

iPhone "A" could write some data to a tag, which iPhone "B" then read, but it would be quite cumbersome.

Comment: can you update this answer ? As there are several applications I have seen that makes an iPhone an NFC tag.

Comment: Can you give an example of such an app?  HCE is not available to apps.

Comment: Here are some latest news for the subway in France - using iPhone as NFC tag https://www.numerama.com/tech/681957-comment-recharger-un-passe-navigo-avec-un-iphone.html
https://www.phonandroid.com/ratp-liphone-se-transformera-enfin-en-pass-navigo-en-2023.html

Comment: https://m2050.media/en/ticketing-one-year-later-the-navigo-pass-finally-available-on-iphone/ <-- in English

Comment: I'm up-voting this question, it is very relevant

Comment: The first article talks about adding value to your physical card and replacing the physical card with an Android device. In terms of replacing the physical card with an iPhone it says "What about the iPhone? This time, it all depends on Apple, which is actively testing the solution from its Californian laboratories. At the moment, it is not possible to replace a Navigo card with an iPhone. Other cities, such as Lyon, accept the iPhone as a way to pay for the metro directly at the terminals to enter the platforms, thanks to Apple Pay."

Comment: The second article says that in 2023 the ability to replace a Navigo pass with an iPhone may come, but there are no details.  If such a facility was provided it would probably be through direct co-operation between Apple and the transport authority.  For example, my supermarket loyalty card is added to Apple Wallet and works via NFC, but the large supermarket chain worked with Apple and their payment terminal provider to implement Value Added Services (VAS).  This is not a capability that is available to "normal" developers

Comment: And, indeed, the third article mentions the special capability that was provided by Apple to allow access to NFC - This would probably be via the VAS capability I mentioned.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254206/discussion-between-axil-and-paulw11).