# Can iPhone act as an NFC Tag?

Tags: ios, swift, nfc, core-nfc

I want to know if an iPhone device can work as an NFC Tag. I want to establish a connection between two iPhone devices using NFC.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57268087/can-we-transfer-data-between-two-iphone-devices-using-nfc-in-ios

Answer (score 0):

yes connection between two iPhone device using NFC Tag. but its to restricted you can use low BLE to establish connection between two iPhone device.

Comment: but I need an NFC Tag object to establish that connection? for example am NFC sticker